# 'Unauthorized' error when creating a hello-world Team with Graph API .NET SDK with Client Credential Flow

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, unauthorized

I've created an app registration and granted the necessary permissions and then some (+ the admin consent):

[image: Screenshot of app permissions]

I add the code to authenticate and create a Team:

```
            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                        .Create("...")
                        .WithTenantId("...")
                        .WithClientSecret("...")
                        .Build();

        ClientCredentialProvider authenticationProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
        GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

        var team = new Team
        {
            DisplayName = "My Sample Team",
            Description = "My Sample Team’s Description",
            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"template@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')"}
            }
        };

        var t =  graphServiceClient.Teams
            .Request()
            .AddAsync(team).Result;

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!" + t.Id);
```

Result: Unauthorized

Comment: Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide screenshots.

Comment: Even though all the permissions are granted, many times those wont reflect in token. Retry again and check your new token in [Jwt.ms[(https://jwt.io/) as @CarlZhao suggested. Make sure all the permission reflect in token.

Comment: Hi,If you have any questions, I will answer you as soon as possible.

Comment: Closing this thread

Answer (score 0):

You are using an example of **delegated permissions**:

[image]

If you need an example of using **application permissions** and creating a team using `client credential flow`, you should refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp%2Chttp#example-2-application-permissions):

[image]